# Wrap the Content inside the Input Value

Tags: html

Is there any way to wrap the content with the input field, in my case is taking a size, but I would like for example if it is the value "123" for the input to be wrapped around the text, and when we type more words it grows in size, without having a fixed size like this in the screenshot.

Screenshot of the Input Text Field [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhEVK.png)

My Component structure JSX:

```
 <Container {...props}>
    <Input placeholder="New Skill" />
    <AddIcon color="#0056FC" />
 </Container>
```

Here is CSS, using Styled Components:

```
const Container = styled.section`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    gap: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.border};
`

const Input = styled.input`
    font-family: 'Manrope';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    color: #455560;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
    display: flex;

    &::placeholder{
        color: #0056FC;
    }
`
```

Comment: By the way, your are using placeholder wrong. Your placeholder should be a label.

Answer (score 1):

I think now that must work.

```css
span {
  padding: 5px;
}
     
div {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Input Field :</span>
  <input type="text" oninput="this.size = this.value.length + 1"  size="1">
</div>
```

Comment: So I tried this but the div is not expanding, I have width auto but still no, thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you check the new edit, I have added the component itself?

Comment: There is no div in this code. What do you mean?

Comment: Yes, I see, but the problem is that I have wrapped the input in a div, so I can add a new button.

Comment: I think I missed the div or you did'nt mention it first, whatever. I have edited the  code and it must work.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mentioned it, but still is not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You've already got the right answer, I just wanted to show the `contenteditable` strategy to achieve the same result:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

#field {
  min-width: 3rem;   /*3 chars min length*/   
  border: 3px solid gray;
  cursor: text;  
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">  
  <h1 contentEditable="true" id="field"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this also, the div is not expanding

Comment: Thanks anyway,

Did you check the new edit, I have added the component itself.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't expand the div while your write inside the box ... the snippet works to me maybe you have an old browser. Anyway mine was not intended to be an answer but just show a concept. I didn't see the updates to your question but I think you should stick with other answers better facing the input type text scenario